# cython portability between python2 and python3 unicode objects

Tags: cython

I need to write some high-performance unicode processing logic and the differences between python2 and python3's Unicode object are significant.

I am only just beginning to figure out how to accomplish this and the following snippet is giving me trouble:

```
from six.text_type import unicode
from cpython.version cimport PY_MAJOR_VERSION
cdef extern from "Python.h":
    int PyUnicode_KIND ( object o )
def unicode_size ( unicode u ):
    if PY_MAJOR_VERSION == 2:
        return sizeof ( Py_UNICODE )
    else:
        return PyUnicode_KIND ( u )
```

This code executes and runs in both python 2 and 3. However, python2's c compiler is giving me "warning C4013: 'PyUnicode_KIND' undefined; assuming extern returning int"

Normally I could suppress this sort of warning by giving the c compiler an extern declaration for the function, knowing that the linker would throw a tantrum if I actually tried to link against it.

However, I can't figure out how to create extern declarations within cython so that the compiler is happy.

I'm not interested in shutting off the warning with command-line parameters, I'm trying to keep compilation simple and straight-forward and I'm one of those "warnings are errors" fanatics. This logic is simple enough to fit within a single pyx file. Also, the prevailing wisdom is that the generated C code should compile in both Python 2 and Python 3, so I'm trying to keep with that.

To make things even more ridiculous, when I look at the generated C code, there's a __Pyx_PyUnicode_KIND() which does exactly what I want, but if I try to call that from my cython code it says it doesn't exist. If the above is impossible, is there a way I can access these portability macros?

Maybe I'm stressing about nothing. Obviously premature optimization is the devil, but my limited experience so far is that for maximum performance, I need to access the pointers behind the python objects or the safety wrappers absolutely kill performance. Is there another way to go about processing a unicode input and generating another unicode output without resorting to version-specific C apis?

---------- UPDATE ----------

Thanks to @ead I was able to develop a solution that met all my criteria. For anybody else that wants to accumulate UCS4 characters in a buffer in Cython and then convert that to a unicode object when done, this is how I solved the problem inline within my .pyx file:

```
cdef extern from *:
    """
    // This is C code that will be passed through to xmlwalk.c as-is:
    PyObject* PyUnicode_FromUCS4 ( Py_UCS4* s, Py_ssize_t size )
    {
#if PY_VERSION_HEX >= 0x03030000
        return PyUnicode_FromKindAndData ( PyUnicode_4BYTE_KIND, s, size );
#elif Py_UNICODE_SIZE == 4
        return PyUnicode_FromUnicode ( s, size );
#elif Py_UNICODE_SIZE == 2
        // WARNING: this version of the code rewrites s in-place as UTF-16.
        // `s` no longer contains valid UCS4 code points upon return.
        Py_UNICODE* dst = (Py_UNICODE*)s;
        Py_ssize_t dst_size = 0;
        Py_ssize_t i;
        for ( i = 0; i < size; i++ )
        {
            Py_UCS4 c = s[i];
            //printf ( "src[%i]=%i (0x%x)\\n", i, (int)c, (int)c );
            if ( c < 0x10000 )
            {
                // assert ( c < 0xD800 || c > 0xDFFF ); // disabled for performance reasons
                dst[dst_size++] = (Py_UNICODE)c;
                //printf ( "dst[%i]=%i (0x%x)\\n", dst_size-1, (int)dst[dst_size-1], (int)dst[dst_size-1] );
            }
            else
            {
                dst[dst_size++] = 0xD800 | (c >> 10);
                //printf ( "dst[%i]=%i (0x%x)\\n", dst_size-1, (int)dst[dst_size-1], (int)dst[dst_size-1] );
                dst[dst_size++] = 0xDC00 | (c & 0x3FF);
                //printf ( "dst[%i]=%i (0x%x)\\n", dst_size-1, (int)dst[dst_size-1], (int)dst[dst_size-1] );
            }
        }
        return PyUnicode_FromUnicode ( dst, dst_size );
#else
        assert(0); // could not determine correct unicode type
#endif
    }
    """
    PyObject* PyUnicode_FromUCS4 ( Py_UCS4* s, Py_ssize_t size )
```

Comment: Perhaps this would be a more succinct way to state my question: Is there a way in Cython to take advantage of Python C API functions (that are only available in certain versions of Python) in a way that doesn't cause problems for older versions of Python? With adequate runtime guards obviously

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing: You should care about warnings.

You must be aware, that the comparison `PY_MAJOR_VERSION == 2` is done during the run-time and is not a preprocessor directive, thus the symbol `PyUnicode_KIND` (after all, in ANSI C (C89, C90) no prototype is needed, the compiler infers the prototype  and so the extension gets compiled) might find its way also in the extension for Python2. It doesn't happen in a build with optimization on, because the optimizer can see the value of `PY_MAJOR_VERSION` during the compile time and optimizes the wrong branch out and thus also the reference to `PyUnicode_KIND`.

However, if you build in debug, without the optimization on (`-O0`) the build will fail. At least on Linux  - it will be built - per default undefined symbols are allowed in shared objects, but during the import it will fail because loader will not find the symbol `PyUnicode_KIND`. Not sure what happens on Windows though...

I don't think `__Pyx_PyUnicode_KIND` is supposed to be used in Cython (even if it might be convenient sometimes) - the `__Pyx_XXXX`-function aren't mentioned in documentation, so they are probably not meant to be a stable API and are only implementation details. However, you could misuse the feature to resolve  [name collisions](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/external_C_code.html#resolving-naming-conflicts-c-name-specifications):

```
cdef extern from *:  
    #put "__Pyx_PyUnicode_KIND" into the C-code, whenever my_PyUnicode_KIND is used:   
    int my_PyUnicode_KIND "__Pyx_PyUnicode_KIND" (object u) 

def unicode_size(u):
    my_PyUnicode_KIND(u)
```

Now, everytime you use `my_PyUnicode_KIND` is used, Cython puts `__Pyx_PyUnicode_KIND` into the C-code.

---

But as said, `__Pyx_XXXX` functions are probably only implementation details and thus not a stable API. A more stable approach would be the following:

What you actually trying to achieve is the follow C-code which uses preprocessor:

```
#include <Python.h>

//you might want to use  CYTHON_INLINE instead of inline
static inline int unicode_size(PyObject *o){
    //actually PyUnicode_KIND is defined since CPython3.3:
    #if PY_VERSION_HEX > 0x03030000 && defined(PyUnicode_KIND)
          return PyUnicode_KIND(o);
    #else
          return sizeof(Py_UNICODE);
    #endif
}
```

For Python2 the preprocessor would pick the right branch and the symbol `PyUnicode_KIND` will never land in the produced object file.

As Cython's [conditional statements](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/language_basics.html#conditional-statements)  are working a little bit different (firstly `PY_MAJOR_VERSION`&Co are not predefined compile-time names and secondly it is not translated into C-preprocessors, but only the right branch is translated to C), so one way to achieve your goal:

1. Define "unicodesize.h"-header with the code from above.
2. Import it as usual into the Cython-module:

   ```
    cdef export from "unicodesize.h":
         int unicode_size(object o)
   ```
3. Depending on how you build, you might need to add the right folder to the include-path in the setup-file.

An alternative would be to [include C-code verbatim](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/external_C_code.html#including-verbatim-c-code).

Comment: Actually I'm a Windows developer. I discovered Py_UCS4 exists in both py2 and py3 and that if I assign unicode values to it, both py2 and py3 will do the right thing. I redesigned with this in mind and performance is acceptable. Studying cython -a, the only yellow parts of my hot path left are where I insert Py_UCS4 values into a pre-allocated list object. I know I can solve this in C, but I'm hoping for a "pure" Cython solution. I need to be able to drop this into multiple projects as a single file without figuring out how to get it to compile.

Comment: @royce3 Not sure how Windows handles it. On Linux it works for optimized builds but not for builds with `-O0`.

Comment: @royce3 in your question there is not enough context so it is impossible to suggest something. However, I found a way to use `__Pyx_PyUnicode_KIND` from Cython, if you are still interested - see my update.

Comment: Thank You! Your link to the page about name collisions helped me find the documentation how to embed C code within my pyx file instead of having to write it in a separate file. I have edited my post with how I solved the problem and accepted your answer.